# toggleClass of div if first div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle the class of a `#klapp` (from `.klapp` to `.klappe`) when a click occur inside `#label-it`. Even the `#klapp` itself is clicked. I can't use unique ids.

```js
$('#label-it').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".filter-panel").toggleClass('klapp');
  $(this).next(".filter-panel").toggleClass('klappe');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="label-it" class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
      <div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label>
</div>
<div id="label-it" class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
      <div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label>
</div>
<div id="label-it" class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
      <div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label>
</div>
<div id="label-it" class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
      <div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label>
</div>
```

My first approach was this, but it only changed the first div of `#label-it`

```
$('#label-it').click(function(){
  $("#klapp").toggleClass('klapp');
  $("#klapp").toggleClass('klappe');
});
```

Comment: I'm sry, i've edited my Question

Comment: You seem to be aware of this, but still: an id is supposed to be unique. Here's the proper way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6tfbjn73/ (in case you're learning from w3schools, please don't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two issues here. Firstly you have repeated `id` attributes on several elements, which is invalid. You need to remove them all and just use the `class` available on each.

Secondly, `next()` searches for sibling elements, yet `.filter-panel` is a child of `.label-it`. As such you can use `find()`. You also need to select the `div` within `.filter-panel` as that's what holds the `.klapp` class. Try this:

```js
$('.label-it').click(function() {
  $(this).find(".filter-panel div").toggleClass('klapp klappe');
});
```

```css
.klapp {
  color: #CCC;
}

.klappe {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
    <div class="klapp">A</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
    <div class="klapp">B</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
    <div class="klapp">C</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="label-it">
  <label class="filter-panel">
    <div class="klapp">D</div>
  </label>
</div>
```